# How can I combine two CIImages with alpha?

Tags: swift, image-processing, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

In my project, I want to combine two CIImages together.
To do this I use "CISourceInCompositing"

```
if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISourceInCompositing") {


        let bgImage = inputImage
        var filterImage = resizeCIImage(image: filterImage, newWSize: bgImage.extent.size)

        filterImage = setOpacity(image: filterImage, alpha: opacity)

        currentFilter.setValue(filterImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        currentFilter.setValue(bgImage, forKey: kCIInputBackgroundImageKey)

        guard let outputImage = currentFilter.outputImage else {
            return CIImage()
        }
                        
        return outputImage
    }
```

But I want to change the opacity of the "kCIInputImageKey"
So I use this method:

```
func setOpacity (image : CIImage, alpha : Double) ->CIImage {
        
        guard let overlayFilter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix") else { fatalError() }
        let overlayRgba: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, alpha]
        let alphaVector: CIVector = CIVector(values: overlayRgba, count: 4)
        overlayFilter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        overlayFilter.setValue(alphaVector, forKey: "inputAVector")
        
        return overlayFilter.outputImage!
    }
```

But the image that I obtain different than what I want:

[image]

Do you have any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `CISourceOverCompositing` instead of `CISourceInCompositing`.

Definition of `CISourceInCompositing`:

```
Uses the background image to define what to leave in the input image, effectively cropping the input image.
```

Definition of `CISourceOverCompositing`

```
Places the input image over the input background image.
```

See information and sample outputs for other CoreImage composite operations here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISourceOverCompositing

Comment: I used "CISourceInCompositing" because I need to filter PNG images without background. With "CISourceOverCompositing" also the transparent parts are overlayed by the filter. But I add a blend function after "CISourceOverCompositing" to mask the image. Thanks